# Get value of ngb-rating in typescript angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap, rating

I have used ngb-rating component and on click I am calling a function. This code is in forloop so i have to get data through id

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]=item.Client_Rating id={{item.BookingId}}>
    <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
        <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" (click)="somethingChanged(item.BookingId)">&#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-rating>
```

The function I have written is as below

```
somethingChanged(BookingId){    
    var num1= ((document.getElementById(BookingId) as HTMLInputElement));
    console.log(num1);
}
```

The value which i get in num1 variable is

```
<ngb-rating aria-valuemin="0" class="d-inline-flex" role="slider" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-rate="9" id="179" aria-valuemax="10" aria-valuenow="9" aria-valuetext="9 out of 10">
```

I want only value 9. How to get it?

Comment: Can you write working example at stackbliz?

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
somethingChanged(item){    
    var num1= item.Client_Rating;
    console.log(num1);
}
```

And change parameters in function call :

`(click)="somethingChanged(item)"`

Comment: Yes it is giving me the value but the last one not the updated one. Eg if prior value is 2 , then I changed to 6 it will give me 2, then again if i change to 8 it will give me 6

Answer (score 0):

```
<ngb-rating name="{{item.BookingId}}" [(ngModel)]="item.Client_Rating"  [(rate)]=item.Client_Rating  (click)="updateClientRatings(item.BookingId,item.Client_Rating)">
                                    <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index" >
                                      <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" >&#9733;</span>
                                    </ng-template>
                                  </ngb-rating>
```

This is what I tried and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
 <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100 (click)="somethingChanged(index+1)">
  &#9733;
 </span>
</ng-template>
```

to get the clicked value!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is to catch the event emitted when the user selects a new rating: rateChange: EventEmitter;

In your HTML:

```
<ngb-rating [(rate)]="item.Client_Rating" (rateChange)="somethingChanged(item.BookingId)"></ngb-rating>
```

In your component:

```
somethingChanged(bookingId) {
   console.log(this.item.Client_Rating)
}
```

If you use (click), the event emitted will be before the (rateChange) event so this is why you get the old value.